# pixijs very slow in mobile compared to css

Tags: performance, canvas, pixi.js

I'm testing PIXIjs for a simple 2D graphics, basically I'm sliding tiles with some background color and borders animation, plus I'm masking some parts of the layout. 
While it works great in desktops it's really slower than the same slide+animations made with pure css in mobile devices (where by the way I'm using crosswalk+cordova so the browser is always the same)
For moving tiles and animating color I'm calling requestAnimationFrame for each tile and I've disabled PIXI's ticker:

```
ticker.autoStart = false;
        ticker.stop();
```

This slowness could be due to a weaker GPU on mobiles? or is just about the way I use PIXI?

I'm not showing the full code because is quite long ~ 800 lines.

The following is the routine I use for each tile once a slide is captured:

```
   const animateTileBorderAndText = (tileObj, steps, _color, radius, textSize, strokeThickness, _config) => {
    let pixiTile = tileObj.tile;
    let s = 0;
    let graphicsData = pixiTile.graphicsData[0];
    let shape = graphicsData.shape;
    let textStyle = pixiTile.children[0].style;
    let textInc = (textSize - textStyle.fontSize) / steps;
    let strokeInc = (strokeThickness - textStyle.strokeThickness) / steps;

    let prevColor = graphicsData.fillColor;
    let color = _color !== null ? _color : prevColor;
    let alpha = pixiTile.alpha;
    let h = shape.height;
    let w = shape.width;
    let rad = shape.radius;
    let radiusInc = (radius - rad) / steps;

    let r = (prevColor & 0xFF0000) >> 16;
    let g = (prevColor & 0x00FF00) >> 8;
    let b = prevColor & 0x0000FF;
    let rc = (color & 0xFF0000) >> 16;
    let rg = (color & 0x00FF00) >> 8;
    let rb = color & 0x0000FF;
    let redStep = (rc - r) / steps;
    let greenStep = (rg - g) / steps;
    let blueStep = (rb - b) / steps;
    let paintColor = prevColor;
    let goPaint = color !== prevColor;
    let animate = (t) => {
        if (s === steps) {
            textStyle.fontSize = textSize;
            textStyle.strokeThickness = strokeThickness;

            //pixiTile.tint = color;
            if (!_config.SEMAPHORES.slide) {
                _config.SEMAPHORES.slide = true;
                PUBSUB.publish(_config.SLIDE_CODE, _config.torusModel.getData());
            }


            return true;
        }


        if (goPaint) {
            r += redStep;
            g += greenStep;
            b += blueStep;
            paintColor = (r << 16) + (g << 8) + b;
        }

        textStyle.fontSize += textInc;
        textStyle.strokeThickness += strokeInc;
        pixiTile.clear()
        pixiTile.beginFill(paintColor, alpha)
        pixiTile.drawRoundedRect(0, 0, h, w, rad + radiusInc * (s + 1))
        pixiTile.endFill();
        s++;
        return requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    };
    return animate();
};
```

the above function is called after the following one, which is called for each tile to make it slide.

```
    const slideSingleTile = (tileObj, delta, axe, conf, SEM, tilesMap) => {
    let tile = tileObj.tile;
    let steps = conf.animationSteps;
    SEM.slide = false;
    let s = 0;
    let stepDelta = delta / steps;
    let endPos = tile[axe] + delta;
    let slide = (time) => {
        if (s === steps) {
            tile[axe] = endPos;
            tileObj.resetPosition();

            tilesMap[tileObj.row][tileObj.col] = tileObj;
            return tileObj.onSlideEnd(axe == 'x' ? 0 : 2);
        }
        tile[axe] += stepDelta;
        s++;
        return requestAnimationFrame(slide);
    };

    return slide();
};
```

For each finger gesture a single column/row (of NxM matrix of tiles) is slided and animated using the above two functions.

It's the first time I use canvas.
 I red that canvas is way faster then DOM animations and I red very good review of PIXIjs, so I believe I'm doing something wrong.

Can someone help?

Comment: Have you tried to just debug it, to check which part of the code takes longest? Even just timing the parts and showing them with console.log. That would be at least a good start to check what might be the bottleneck.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick answer. I've profiled it on desktop (chrome) and I can see it spends 50% of the time in Update Layer Tree. now I've to compare it against the css version. Unfortunately on mobile it gets to slow when the profiling is on and doesn't even start the animation. ( this is due to the poor hardware performance of my samsung)

Comment: I looked a bit more and try to give some points. If you use canvas and not wegl, GPU is not used. Webgl uses GPU. If you animate a lot of tiles it looks like a heavy operation. You shouls try to do as little as possible in every frame. Also if possible just move objects and change their properties rather than creating new ones. Like creating new rounded rectangle

Comment: Hi, Hachi, and thanks again for your help. It seems that in pixijs the only way to change a rectangle layout (background color borders...) is to redraw...I hope I can be proved wrong but I've tried to change tint and other variables directly and nothing but unwanted effects are going to happen. About WebGL the documentation (https://github.com/pixijs/pixi.js/) says the following: "The application will create a renderer using WebGL, if possible". how can I check whether pixi is  using WebGL or just canvas?

Comment: BTW I did some more debuggin and I've found out that all the computation spent in "Update Layer Tree" was not due to pixijs but to other stuff I was doing in the dom. Thanks again for recalling me that I'm a developer and I should have (and use) a debugging skill.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Well I'm just simply happy that my comments were useful :).

Answer (score 1):

In the end I'm a complete donk...
The issue is not with pixijs.

Basically I was forcing 60fps! The number of steps to complete the animation is set to 12 that implies 200ms animation at 60FPS (using requestAnimationFrame) but in low end devices its going to be obviously slower.
Css animation works with timing as parameter so it auto adapt FPS to devices hardware.

To solve the issue I'm adapting the number of steps during animations, basically if animations takes longer than 200ms I just reduce number of steps proportionally.

I hope this could be of help for each web developer used to css animation who have just started developing canvas.